# Intersection of a set of matrices nonzero over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, finite-fields, matrix-rank

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field of $q=2^k$ elements, $n$ be an odd number. Consider a set of $n$ by $n$ symmetric matrices $\mathbf{Q}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{Q}_n$ whose entries are randomly selected from the field $\mathbb{F}$, and the diagonals are all zero. (assume they are all of rank $n-1$).

I would like to compute the probability that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n \text{Im}\mathbf{Q}_i$ is nonzero.

I know that a vector is in  the Image of a matrix if and only if it is in the column space of that matrix.

Moreover, for a nonzero vector $\mathbf{v}$, the probability that it is in $\text{Im}\mathbf{Q}_i$ is $\frac{q^{n-1}-1}{q^n}\approx 1/q$.

But it is clear that first several intersections will not be $\{\mathbf{0}\}$ by the formula $\dim(U\cap V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)-\dim(U+V)$.

Comment: How do you conclude that they are all of rank $n-1$? Or is that a further requirement you are imposing? I can see why they have rank **at most** $n-1$.

Comment: Yes, they are at most n-1. But since the entries are all random, I assume that they are of rank $n-1$.

Comment: If the **entries** are all random, you can't assume that. The entries could all be 0 (with some nonzero probability). Do you instead mean that the **matrices are selected randomly** from the collection of alternating matrices with rank $n-1$?

Comment: Yes, let us assume that the matrices are all of rank n-1.

Comment: As I said, if you **assume** that the matrices are all of rank $n-1$, then you **cannot select the entries randomly**, since some selections of entries for the matrix will give a  different rank. This is important since you are trying to compute a probability.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted to roughly estimate the probability and see if it matches my experiments.

Comment: Then you will need to specify how you are selecting these matrices: Are you selecting random entries for the matrix and then discarding the matrix if it has rank less than $n-1$? Are you forming all of the rank $n-1$ matrices and then selecting $n$ of these matrices randomly? Are you using some other method?

Comment: Yes! Sorry about not describing my question precisely.

Comment: How do I prove that the intersection of their images is trivial if and only if the null spaces span the full space?

Comment: The case for two matrices is easy, the null Q1 is a nonzero multiple of the null Q2. But for the induction step, I am confused. Let $U=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k-1} Q_i$ and V=$Q_{k}$, how do I compute $\dim(U+V)$? I know it is at least $n-1$, but how do I know it is full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the questions mentioned in the comments about how exactly the matrix entries are selected randomly while ensuring that the resulting matrices have rank $n-1$, I cannot say anything about the probabilities you are trying to compute. But I can give some insight to the the general problem about when a collection of $n$ subspaces of dimension $n-1$ have a trivial intersection.

If $Q$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with rank $n-1$, then $\mathrm{Im}(Q)$ is a hyperplane of $\mathbb{F}^{n}$. If we have a hyperplane $H$ and $U$ is any subspace, then
$$\dim(U \cap H) = \begin{cases} \dim(U) & \ U \subseteq H\\ \dim(U) -1 & \mbox{ otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

Putting $H_{i} = \mathrm{Im}(Q_{i})$ for $1\leq i \leq n$, we see that the only way for $\cap_{i=1}^{n} H_{i} = \{0\}$ is for each $1 \leq k \leq n$,
$$\cap_{i=1}^{k-1}H_{i} \not\subseteq H_{k},$$
or equivalently, for all $1 \leq k \leq n$,
$$\dim\left(\cap_{i=1}^{k}H_{i}\right) = n-k.$$
This what we mean when we say the hyperplanes $H_{1}, \ldots, H_{n}$ must be in
*general position*.

A good way to determine whether hyperplanes are in general position is to work in the dual space; we replace each hyperplane $H_{i}$ with $H_{i}^{\perp}$, if we have $H_{i} = \mathrm{Im}(Q_{i})$ (you say you are working with the column space here) then $H_{i}^{\perp} = \mathrm{null}(Q_{i}^{T}) = \mathrm{null}(Q_{i}^{T})$ (here we are working with the right null space) since your matrices are symmetric. Each null space is one-dimensional (I prefer to think of them as points in the projective space).

Now, the correspondence $U \mapsto U^{\perp}$ is an inclusion-reversing map on the subspaces of $\mathbb{F}^{n}$, and we have the correspondence
$$(U_{1} \cap U_{2})^{\perp} = \langle U_{1}^{\perp}, U_{2}^{\perp} \rangle$$
(where $\langle \ldots \rangle$ denotes the span), so having
$$\dim\left(\cap_{i=1}^{k}H_{i}\right) = n-k$$
for all $k$ is equivalent to having
$$\dim\left(\langle H_{1}^{\perp}, \ldots, H_{k}^{\perp}\rangle\right) = k$$
for all $k$, in other words, if we take $v_{i}$ such that $\langle v_{i} \rangle = \mathrm{null}(Q_{i})$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, then
$$\dim\left( \cap_{i=1}^{n} \mathrm{Im}(Q_{i})\right) = \{0\}$$
if and only if $\{v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Why is it true that $H_i^{\perp}$ is disjoint from $H_i$? We usually can't assume that the image and kernel are disjoint?

Comment: @user335468 It is not true in general that $H_{i}^{\perp}$ and $H_{i}$ are disjoint, I don't believe I say or use that? However it is true that $\dim{H_{i}^{\perp}} + \dim{H_{i}} = n$

Comment: @user335468 For the inclusion reversing, you just want to notice that if $S \subseteq H$, then the vectors in $H^{\perp}$ are orthogonal to everything in $S$, so $H^{\perp} \subseteq S^{\perp}$.